# Function to Remove the Decimal Places

Tags: vba, math, math-functions

What is the JavaScript `Math.Floor()` equivalent in VBA?. this function should remove all the decimal places and return only an integer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Of what i remember use the Int() function. ex

```
int(2.99) = 2 ; int(2.1)=2
```

and so on.

Comment: Keep in mind that Int(-5.8) will give -6 which might not be what you expect.

Comment: I am using this to test if a double is an integer is `if x = int(x) then 'integer end if` Is there a better way, without having to throw an error?

Comment: Math.floor(-5.8) in javascript gives also -6, so it is exactly what asked. But if you want "real floor" than you can make -5.8 give -5 by bitwise operation OR 0 (in javascript -5.8|0 ) but i don't know even if it exists in VBA but if it does it will give you -5

Answer (score 6):

be careful that CInt() actually rounds the number, but Int() doesn't.

```
CInt(1.6) ~~ 2
Int(1.6) ~~ 1
```

Comment: Int() still rounds numbers, for example Int(-1.6) = -2

Answer (score 4):

It's `Round()`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim dval As Double
    dval = 1.12345

    Debug.Print Round(dval, 0)
End Sub
```

`0` above specifies the number of decimals you want.

**EDIT:**

Albi Patozi is right. The `equivalent` of `Math.Floor()` is `int()`. I was under the impression that you just wanted to return a number without the decimals. But then I looked up http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp

> > > The floor() method rounds a number DOWNWARDS to the nearest integer, and returns the result.

```
'~~> JavaScript floor() Method
'var a=Math.floor(0.60);    ~~> 0
'var b=Math.floor(0.40);    ~~> 0
'var c=Math.floor(5);       ~~> 5
'var d=Math.floor(5.1);     ~~> 5
'var e=Math.floor(-5.1);    ~~> -6
'var f=Math.floor(-5.9);    ~~> -6

Sub Sample()
    Dim dval(5) As Double, i As Long

    dval(0) = 0.6: dval(1) = 0.4: dval(2) = 5
    dval(3) = 5.1: dval(4) = -5.1: dval(5) = -5.9

    For i = LBound(dval) To UBound(dval)
        Debug.Print Round(dval(i), 0); " ~~ "; Int(dval(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

**RESULT**

ROUND() ~~ INT()

1  ~~  0

0  ~~  0

5  ~~  5

5  ~~  5

-5  ~~ -6

-6  ~~ -6

Answer (score 2):

You could also call one of the Excel worksheet functions from VBA:

### - [`Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor_Math`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.floor(v=office.14).aspx)

### - [`Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.floor(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

For positive values, VBA offers `Int()` and `Fix()` which are functionally equivalent to `Math.floor()`.  However, for negative values, only `Int()` is functionally equivalent to `Math.floor()`.  The VBA function `Fix()` might be what you want if you are only interested in getting the value that is on the left side of the decimal point.

Math.floor(2.8) == 2
Int(2.8) == 2
Fix(2.8) == 2

Math.floor(-2.8) == -3
Int(-2.8) == -3
Fix(-2.8) == -2

[Office VBA Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions)

> Int, Fix Functions
>
> Returns the integer portion of a number.
>
> Syntax
>
> Int(number)
>
> Fix(number)
>
> The required number argument is a Double or any valid numeric
>   expression. If number contains Null, Null is returned.
>
> Remarks
>
> Both Int and Fix remove the fractional part of number and return the
>   resulting integer value.
>
> The difference between Int and Fix is that if number is negative, Int
>   returns the first negative integer less than or equal to number,
>   whereas Fix returns the first negative integer greater than or equal
>   to number. For example, Int converts -8.4 to -9, and Fix converts -8.4
>   to -8.
>
> Fix(number) is equivalent to:
>
> Sgn(number) * Int(Abs(number))